# Module 'urllib' has no attribute 'request'

Tags: python-3.x, urllib, python-import

I tried using this string

```
thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(theurl)
```

with this

```
import urllib.request
```

and I keep getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\email.py", line 2, in <module>
    import urllib.request
  File "C:\Users\Alonzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 86, in <module>
    import email
  File "C:\Users\Alonzo\programming\Email Bot\email.py", line 6, in <module>
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(theurl)            
AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'request'
```

I'm not sure what this problem could be.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't just do `import urllib`, and then `thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(theurl)`? Because that sould cause the error you are seeing. Otherwise, I cannot reproduce. Please show all relevant code.

Comment: import urllib.request
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    theurl = 'https://twitter.com/Imaqtpielol'
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(theurl)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage, 'html.parser')

    print(soup.title)

Comment: What happens if you do `import urllib.request; urllib.request.urlopen` in a Python 3 interpreter? Your exact code works fine for me.

Comment: <function urlopen at 0x0422DF18> This came up in IDLE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK here is what I think is happening.

When you import `urllib.request`, one of the first things that happens is that `urllib.request` [tries to import a standard library module called `email`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/urllib/request.py#L86) (this module can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email-examples.html)). You have a personal module in your project called `email` (`"C:\Users\Alonzo\programming\Email Bot\email.py"`) which tries to use `urllib.request.urlopen` which hasn't been defined yet in `urllib.request` (since that happens only *after* `email` is imported).

`urllib.request` is trying to import your local `email` module instead of the intended standard library module, which breaks everything.

Try renaming `"C:\Users\Alonzo\programming\Email Bot\email.py"` to something else like `emailbot.py` (or anything that doesn't shadow a standard library module or installed module you intend to use) and see if that solves your problem.